# HorizontalScrollView in ExpandableList Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, horizontalscrollview

am trying to implement horizontalScrollView in expandableList group. But group is not expanding while clicking. When i remove the horizontalScrollView  it works normally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/boilerbg"
android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tag_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/group_down" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/group_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#727272"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView can only contain one object.

Replace the TextView with a LinearLayout (or which Layout you prefer) and let it hold all your TextViews.

Comment: with TextViews I mean your title and expandibleList group